# Why does Apache Maven change the compileSourceRoots default value?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, pom.xml, javac

I have copied my pom  based application project into another directory 
and built the original project with the paraneters `compile deploy`.

Maven's  default value of `compileSourceRoots` is `[projectname]\src\java` which is fine.

Maven's output:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [D:\ccviews\ovandunen_main\TWCS_HEN\wcg\source\Common\src\main\java]
```

If I change the directory of the copied project and run `mvn compile deploy`  I get a different `compileSourceRoots` value which is `[projectname]\src\test\java`.

Maven's output:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [D:\ccviews\ovandunen_loesch\TWCS_HEN\wcg\source\Common\src\test\java]
```

Why and when does Maven change its default value?

This the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>com.org.eth</groupId>
        <artifactId>WaysideGateway</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.org.eth</groupId>
    <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Common</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!---
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Enable dependency if you want to use H2 -->
                <!-- Also update glassfish-resources.xml to use H2 connection information -->
                <!--
                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                     <version>1.3.166</version>
                     <scope>test</scope>
                 </dependency>
                -->
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- The surefire plugin is configured to pass a system property to GlassFish to retarget the derby log file -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <java.util.logging.config.file>
                                    ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
                                </java.util.logging.config.file>
                                <derby.stream.error.file>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
                                </derby.stream.error.file>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <!--
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>arquiilian-repo</id>
                    <name>Arquillian repositor</name>
                    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public </url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            -->
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```